# RichTextBox - Add text to top with multiple colors (only latest line is showing)

Tags: c#, logging, colors, richtextbox

I'm trying to replicate a log window, so the most recent log should appear at the top - most visible. Thus, I need to add a text to the top (no problem) but with multiple colors (problem).

First I store the original text. (it's rtf or text - tried both)
And then I add the new text, with a username and then a message. The username should be one color and the message another. It's always single lined too.

All I get by my method is that when appending the old text or the old RTF text, the latest "log" only shows.

```
public void AddLog(Log log)
{
        try
        {
            string oldText = this.richTextBox1.Rtf;

            this.richTextBox1.Text = log.User + ": " + log.Message + "\n";
            this.richTextBox1.Select(0, log.User.Length);
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.GreenYellow;
            this.richTextBox1.Select(log.User.Length + 2, log.Message.Length);
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White;
            this.richTextBox1.DeselectAll();
            this.richTextBox1.Rtf += oldText;

        }
        catch { }
}
```

Is this even possible? Because it doesn't save the old RTF text and the old RTF text can't be appended after the new text, which means I probably have to add newest text below which isn't what I want.

If I instead of saving the "RTF" text, the format (colors) will disappear and will only show one color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but try this

```
public void AddLog(Log log)
{
    try
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectAll();            
        string oldText = this.richTextBox1.SelectedRtf;

        this.richTextBox1.Text = log.User + ": " + log.Message + "\n";
        this.richTextBox1.Select(0, log.User.Length);
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        this.richTextBox1.Select(log.User.Length + 2, log.Message.Length);
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White;
        this.richTextBox1.DeselectAll();
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = this.richTextBox1.TextLength;
        this.richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = oldText;
        this.richTextBox1.DeselectAll();

    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what the difference is of selecting the SelectedRtf text first or just copying the .Rtf text (formated text) and then adding it again. But this worked. All other tries have un-formatted the text after adding new text, or been weird for some reason.

Comment: What I understand is `Rtf` property gives complete `Rtf format` where as `SelectedRtf` gives a portion of it. I'll say it like this releted with HTML. `Rtf` + `Rtf` is like `<html>sometags</html><html>sometags2</html>` where as inserting `SelectedRtf` affects only subset so `<html>sometags,sometags2</html>`. As a result first format results in Invalid data where as second not. :)